# Is there any good strategy for computing null space of a matrix with entries $\cos x$ and $\sin x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-mathematics

For example, say

$A= \left ( \begin{matrix} \cos x & -\sin x & 0 \\ \cos y \sin x & \cos x \cos y & -\sin y \\ \sin x \sin y  & \sin y \cos x & \cos y \end{matrix} \right)$.

How do i conpute null space of $A-I$?

Since I don't know whether $\cos x$ , the 1-1 entry, is $0$ or not, I cannot simply take elementary operators on this matrix.

Is there any good strategy to find its null space?

(Note that $A$ is *just* an example. I'm asking how to compute null space of such matrices with entries $\cos x$, $\sin x$, $\cos y$, $\sin y$...)

Comment: That matrix is orthogonal.

Comment: @chris eagle I don't get why the fact this mAtrix is orthogonal makes it easy to evaluate null vectors.. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Katlus: an orthogonal matrix has an inverse (namely its transpose) so must be of full rank.

Comment: @Ben i'm really sorry. I meant the null space of $A-I$, not $A$.

Comment: @Katlus: now you've asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451796/is-there-a-good-strategy-for-computing-eigenspace-corresponding-to-1-of-a-matr , maybe revert this question to its original form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the rank of a matrix is equal the the dimension of the space spanned by either its rows or its columns. So if you can prove the rows or columns are linearly independent, it must have full rank (i.e. trivial null space).

In this case, the dot product of any two distinct rows/columns is 0, and none of the rows/columns can be identically zero, so you're done.

In fact, the matrix is orthogonal, since all the rows/columns are in fact of length 1 as well. In some sense this isn't so surprising, because sines and cosines arise naturally in problems about rotations, which are represented by orthogonal matrices.

Comment: i edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

$$\det A=\color{red}{\cos^2x}\cos^2y+\color{green}{\sin^2x}\sin^2y+\color{red}{\cos^2x}\sin^2y+\cos^2y\color{green}{\sin^2x}=\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$$

Thus your matrix is regular $\,\iff \ker A=0\;$

In general you will need to resort to do some calculations as the above one, but I don't think there's a general formula for *the* general case.

Please note we used basic trigonometry above...

Comment: i just edited my post. Please check it again thank you:)

Comment: That's a brand new question and you should leave the present one as it was (since people already took their time to answer it!) and post a new thread

Comment: I have no idea what should be a title for a post i'm gonna post.. It's exactly the same without one line.

Comment: Yes, but people **already** posted answers here...